# Count results from different temp tables

Tags: sql-server-2008, count, multiple-tables

I have different temptables with Branch Names in - I want to do a do count of the Branch Names from each table.
My temptables are #CAT1, #CAT2, #CAT3, #CAT4 and they each look like this:

```
Branch_Name      Friday    Saturday    Sunday 
BranchA        57        53        54  
BranchB        51        23        22
```

I would like a total of all Branch_Name from each temptable (there are no duplicates).
Is this possible?

I've tried this, but I think I should be joining maybe?

```
select COUNT(*)Branch_Name  
into #BranchCount  
from #CAT1, #CAT2, #CAT3, #CAT4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using a `UNION ALL`

Something like

```
select COUNT(*)Branch_Name
FROM    (
            SELECT  *
            FROM    #CAT1
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  *
            FROM    #CAT2
            SELECT  *
            FROM    #CAT3
            SELECT  *
            FROM    #CAT4
        ) t
```